# FFmpeg-php installation error on CentOS 6 x64 bit

Tags: centos, compiling, ffmpeg

I'm trying to install `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg-php`. FFMpeg installed perfectly. When I try to install `ffmpeg-php`, I'm running `./configure` and it's configured fine. However, when I run `make` it gives me the following error:

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c -o ffmpeg_movie.lo
 cc -I. -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/include -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/main -I/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include/libavcodec/ -I/usr/local/include/libavformat/ -I/usr/local/include/libavutil/ -I/usr/local/include/libswscale/ -I/usr/local/include/libavfilter/ -I/usr/local/include/libavdevice/ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -c /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ffmpeg_movie.o
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie___construct’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: ‘list_entry’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:311: error: ‘le’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:346: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘new_le’
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:356: error: ‘new_le’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getComment’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:531: warning: ‘comment’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:760)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:531: warning: ‘comment’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:760)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getTitle’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:546: warning: ‘title’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:757)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:546: warning: ‘title’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:757)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAuthor’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:561: warning: ‘author’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:758)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:561: warning: ‘author’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:758)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getCopyright’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:575: warning: ‘copyright’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:759)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:575: warning: ‘copyright’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:759)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getAlbum’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:590: warning: ‘album’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:761)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:590: warning: ‘album’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:761)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getGenre’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:604: warning: ‘genre’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:764)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:604: warning: ‘genre’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:764)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getTrackNumber’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:619: warning: ‘track’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:763)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘zim_ffmpeg_movie_getYear’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:632: warning: ‘year’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavformat/avformat.h:762)
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c: In function ‘_php_read_av_frame’:
/usr/local/src/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0/ffmpeg_movie.c:1215: warning: ‘avcodec_decode_video’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3656)
make: *** [ffmpeg_movie.lo] Error 1
```

My OS is CentOS 6.4 x86_64 virtuozzo – VPS.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The actual error message is somewhere in the 5-10 lines before what you copied here. You'll need to post more of the make log for anyone to have a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: @Mat : Thank you.. i posted whole error after 'make' command run,

Comment: Please repost the error message. If you look at the above one it has spaces in between the lines (as you scroll over you'll notice it).